# How to align an image in the box exactly center (vertical and horizontal)

Tags: html, css

In my webpage section i use a icon gallery. I insert an image/icon in a div and manage through css for align center (vertical and horizontal). But i found my image align center vertically not exact center in my div. See my code and css.

**css**

```
#main {
width: 170px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
}

#main div{
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
align-self: center;
background:red;
}
```

and

**html**

```
<div id="main">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

See my [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/anmol1976/px52mk5b/)

How to align my image in exact center in body or div?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`

```css
#main {
  width: 170px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#main div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

In case you have some other elements in `#main` but you want `div` to be vertically and horizontally centered you can remove `div` from elements flow with `position: absolute` and use `transform: translate()`.

```css
#main {
  width: 170px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
#main div,
span {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}
span {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: green;
}
#main div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span></span>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a small change is needed to get your desire output. That is include the code `margin: 0 auto;` along with the #main div css. Then the css will be as below.

```
#main div{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    align-self: center;
    background:red;
  margin: 0 auto;/*Newly added one*/
}
```

I've updated your jsfiddle Example. [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/px52mk5b/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this nice little transform translate trick to center things.

In your case

```
   #main {
    width: 170px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    position: relative;
   }

    #main div {
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     background:red;
    }
```

So use position: relative on your parent element and position: absolute on the child element. On the absolute element use left: 50% and top: 50% along with transform: translate(-50%, -50%) and everything should be centered.

Answer (score 0):

add "margin:0 auto;" to your image like this:

```
#main div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/px52mk5b/5/

-I hope this help